# What are some good PHP profilers that can be used?

Tags: php, profiler

I've studied about profilers in PHP... Now I want to know:

What are some good PHP profilers that can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use XDebug and WinCacheGrind to profile php.

Answer (score 7):

Low level profilers - These are modules which are loaded into the php executable, and therefore are a bit harder to setup, but they provide solid results.

- http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof
- http://xdebug.org/

PQP is a code-based profiler.  While probably not as accurate as the low-level profilers mentioned above, it may be all you need if you are looking for some simple metrics.

- http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/

Answer (score 1):

XDebug? http://www.google.com/search?q=php+profiler

Answer (score 1):

See my company's (Semantic Designs) [PHP Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/PHPProfiler.html).  No changes required to the PHP server are needed to use this.

Comment: So, it's not free (as most other cool tools of SD ;) ), I assume?

Comment: It is a commercial product.  I believe none of the others provide a call graph or timing on call subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

One you can use is [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler). Also something nice to note is that if you use frameworks. The framework [kohana](http://www.kohanaphp.com) has a build in profiler that even measures your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).