# Measure website

Tags: web-services, optimization, web, measurement

I was wondering if it is possible to install or use any online service to measure your website's performance? I've seen many just checking the download speed of images, external files etc. But is it possible to meassure how long asp/php code takes to execute?

I have a site running a bit slowly, and it would be very nice with some app/service guiding where to optimize.

Comment: indeed, you should accept answers, that is how the site works.  if you don't participate, people will stop bothering to help you...

Comment: I'm sorry, i will accept answers on my posts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could profile the code.  There are several questions detailing available profilers for many languages.  [.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) or  [Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145373/what-are-some-good-php-profilers-that-can-be-used) for example.  also there are some which deal with asp specifcally, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-asp-net-websites-with-eqatec-profiler), using a free profiler I believe.

Comment: Ended up using http://aspprofiler.sourceforge.net/ which does exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

[YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) is an excellent tool for measuring client side performance of the web site. It will also suggest what you should do in order to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AlertGrid](http://alert-grid.com), basically, it is an app tracing app. You can use it to track ANY metrics or statistics but you have to collect them on your own. It provides alerting (alert rule editor) and data visualisation, it's not a classical profiler tool, but still you may find it useful.