# performance issue in website based on LAMP architecture

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, performance

I have an internal website using LAMP architecture. My main page takes around 10 secs to load the data. There isn't lot of data, around 4-5k records. I dont have any complex MYSQL queries, but have a lot of them i.e. around 10-15 queries. Basically I'm extracting meta-data to display on the page. These are very simple queries. I have lot of PHP and javascript logic which is of medium complexity. I can't remove any of that. I have around 1800 lines of code in that page and I'm using datatables to display data.
The datatable contains 25 columns and lot of html select elements.
So how will I know what is causing performance bottleneck in this page? I tried to be as clear as possible, but please let me know if you have any questions.

Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: check your code for duplicate loop varaibles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use any  php profiler tool like  zend profiler  to see what section is taking much time

http://erichogue.ca/2011/03/linux/profiling-a-php-application/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145373/what-are-some-good-php-profilers-that-can-be-used

Comment: Thanks Zod, I installed xdebug, but can you suggest any profiler which can be used on MAMP, because my application on localhost is using MAMP. Dev and production are in LAMP.

Comment: Thanks all. I used kcachegrind and figured out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get all the data at once. I've had issues in the past where using multiple selects actually takes longer than more efficiently querying (also make sure you use a sql connection for as long as possible). Other than that profiling is the way to go in case your other code needs optimization.